# In Angular2 how do i trigger a set of parallel HTTP calls based on receiving an array of results from a previous http call

Tags: rest, angular, typescript, rxjs

1. I am using Angular2.
2. I have an API to get a list of primary keys from a http REST interface.
3. I then take these primary keys to use read back the actual records using http REST.
4. I then take the whole set of returned http data and return as an array of objects.

I have worked out the code to do this but am VERY unsure if it is doing what I hope and is there a better, neater way to do it.

The code is:

```
getLocations(): Observable<Location[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.locationsUrl}/read`, { headers: this.headers })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json().pks) //Array of primary keys
        .flatMap(x => x)
        .map(pkId => this.http.get(`${this.locationsUrl}/get/${pkId}`, { headers: this.headers })) // Observable of observables (HTTP Calls))
        .mergeAll()
        .map((res: Response) => {
            var returnedObj = res.json();
            var location: Location = returnedObj.result || {};
            location.id = returnedObj.pk;
            return location;
        }) // Observable of result dictionaries
        .toArray();
}
```

I am using Angular2 rc6.

Comment: I also use the same code for release version of Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head I would probably use something less rx.js based as I am still not that familiar with all the operators and the best way to use them. The way I would do it is use a recursive function which makes a http request for the first item in the primary keys array, once the request resolves itself I would push any needed data into a new array, using the the spread operator way and then unshift() the array and pass it back into the same function to fully reduce it. Would then check the length of the array after the unshit() to check for completion. You could probably do something quite nice with the array.reduce() method and use more of a functional programming approach, by composing lots of more smaller functions. I am no expert but that would be my approach if I had to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to an observable, you can provide a callback function; in the example below, I call it `CompleteValidCall`.  `CompleteValidCall()` will only be invoked on a successful get that returns data and not an error.  You place whatever follow on logic you need in the callback function.

```
this._service.valid()
   .subscribe(
      result => this.result = result,
      error => this.error = error,
      () => this.CompleteValidCall()
);

completeValidCall() {
  // the rest of your logic here - only executes on obtaining result.
}
```